# nModBus To SNMP (v3) conversion using Python

Tags: python, c#, network-programming, snmp, python-module

I have multiple hardware they are sending data value to nmodbus.

My task is get this data from nModbus and generate custom MiB file with appropriate value which is send by nModbus and send to other places.

I am succeed for fetching data from nModbus using Python,but I am not understand how to create custome mib file with this

for example device send 30.0 value for high tempreture. Now I need to set this 30.0 value with description with High tempreture in Mib. Can you anyone help me out on this issue. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Unfortunately the sentences in their current form do not describe an SNMP question that anyone can easily answer. Write the question in your native language and use an advanced AI to translate to English please. That's much better than forcing others to guess what you meant.